# API Import extension

Tags: civicontribute

I need to load about 300 pledges from a spreadsheet. The best solution seems to be the API Loader but it is listed as 4.4 we are on 4.6 going to 4.7. Can we get the extension tested for 4.6 and 4.7

Comment: Yes of course you can try to install the extension in Civi 4.6 or Civi 4.7 and when it seems to works and you can inform the developer of the extension that you have used it in 4.6/4.7

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact question here is.  Are you asking if you can test it yourself?  If so, absolutely - you won't be able to download it directly into CiviCRM from the extensions directory, but you can download a zip, unzip it, and upload it to your CiviCRM extensions directory.  Refresh your extensions page and you'll see it appear.

Comment: My hope was the developer would test the extension on 4.6 and 4.7. I did not realize installing the module was basically unzip the file.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If by get the extension tested you mean someone else doing it for you, unless you have an incentive (eg. budget), unlikely to happen, at least at the speed you'd like.

If it's about you or someone in your team testing: please do so!

If you are familiar with git, I would suggest you to install the extension using it, it will be easier if you have to modify something, but otherwise, you can just download the zip and put it in your extension folder.

https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.csvimport.git

Comment: I am very sorry I did not understand the extension process.  I am finding many modules are available in civi, but not well documented and no infrastructure like where Drupal has the directory with comments and and details of bugs. The developer may walk away from an extension, at least there is a place to easily find other folks with the same issue.

Comment: Hi, right now, each extension have their own comments and issue tracker, that's something we'd like improving and easier to found indeed. Most are hosted on github, so that's probably your best place to check if others have similar issues or report bugs